# JQuery - dom manipulation on a variable

Tags: jquery, dom

I have some code as follows..

```
<div class="b-oneColumn w-text">
 <div class="e-text1">
   <textarea id="mce_0" class="tiny" rows="10" ria-hidden="true">Some text here</textarea>
   <span id="mce_0_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin">.....</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

what I am doing is pass $('.w-text') to the following function..

```
processTextForServer : function(widget) {
 var myText = 'mycontent'; 
 var widgetHtml = $('div').append($(widget).clone()).find('.mceEditor').remove().end().html();
}
```

basically, I clone the element, remove the span.mceEditor from the markup and store the html to widgetHtml - no problems there, but I now want to manipulate the html string further as if it were a dom element, but without changing the actual element - and capture the result in a variable for upload to a db. all i need to do is change the textarea text to the contents of myText variable, and then save the entire thing to another variable, but for some reason I am unable to do this, any ideas would be very welcome..

thanks for the comments, have amended accordingly, but overall, what I am trying to achieve is something like this...

```
        var widgetHtml = $('<div>').append(widget.clone()).find('.mceEditor').remove().end().find('.tiny').html('new text').end().html(); 
// this following alert should show me the original chunk of html, MINUS the span.mceEditor AND with the textarea contents changed(manipulated)
alert(widgetHtml);
```

is this possible?

just to re-iterate, Im only interested in the variable - which I plan to send to the server, I dont want to change anything in the actual dom structure itself. 
thanks.

Comment: What is it you need to 'manipulate' what are you trying to get as your end result variable? please provide an EDIT to your original answer and provide what you NEED to get done in a pragmatic format. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you're passing in $('.w-text') to the processTextForServer function then you're later referencing it as $(widget).clone() which is like saying: $($('.w-text')).clone() It should instead be widget.clone()

Answer (score 0):

Check a working example on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/Cs5MC/